# Why will this compile but not allow me to access the function as an extension C#

Tags: c#, enums, extension-methods, intellisense, enumeration

It compiles perfectly fine but won't let me access the method when I have an enumeration array. I have another function that extends a single enum value and it works perfectly on any type of enum and shows up via intellisense but not on enum arrays. Can I not do this or something, it works perfectly fine with string and integer arrays

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
  public static void WriteCompressed (this Enum[] towrite, Stream output)
  {
    .... Function Code ....
  }
}
```

***Update this is what I changed it too you can't cast a defined enumeration array to Enum[]

```
public static class EnumExtensions 
{
     public static void WriteCompressedEnums<T>(this T[] towrite, Stream output) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (towrite == null)
        {
            Serialization.ObjectConversion.writeCompressedInt(output, 0);
            return;
        }
        towrite.Length.WriteCompressed(output);
        Type enumtype = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));
        for (int i = 0; i < towrite.Length; i++)
        {
            Object value = Convert.ChangeType(towrite, enumtype);
            long written;
            if (value is ulong)
            {
                written = (long)((ulong)value);
            }
            else
            {
                written = (long)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(long));
            }
            written.WriteCompressed(output);
        }
        return;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you include the correct namespace in the class you want to use this extension method? And is your class static?

Comment: @KevinBrechbühl Yes my other function for writing a single compressed enum is in the same class as this and I'm using it in the same calling function that needs to call this. It is compiled up to date too

Comment: How it works for me? http://i.imgur.com/Ji6LDnd.png

Comment: @Selman22 Change the Enum[] to a custom or already defined enum array instead of the inherited base class

Comment: can you provide your custom class code ? i don't understand what do you mean `custom or already defined enum array` Enum class can not be inherited

Comment: @Selman22 System.Enum is the base class for all defined enumerations. I said custom referring to enum customeenum {...} or an enumeration already defined in the System etc namespace. Ill provide the class code for it here soon. Apparently you cant cast an already defined enumeration array to an System.Enum[] variable  but you can cast a single defined enumeration to a single System.Enum variable

Comment: @user3141117: Although `System.Enum` is base class of custom defined enumeration, `System.Enum[]` is not the  base of `custom enumeration array`.

Comment: @YK1 Ok I see what you mean, Ill just create a generic function for it instead of trying this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the code to something like

```
public static void WriteCompressed<T>(this T[] towrite, Stream output) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");
    }
    //.... Function Code ...
}
```

And then using it with

```
public enum TADA
{
    Foo,
    Bar
}

public class TADA_NON_ENUM
{
}

public struct TADA_STRUCT
{
}
```

gives

```
TADA[] t = new TADA[1];
t.WriteCompressed(new MemoryStream()); //just fine
TADA_NON_ENUM[] tne = new TADA_NON_ENUM[1];
tne.WriteCompressed(new MemoryStream()); //compile time error
TADA_STRUCT[] ts = new TADA_STRUCT[1];
ts.WriteCompressed(new MemoryStream()); //compile time error
```

**EDIT**

Declared in an extension class, and used in another.

```
public enum TADA
{
    Foo,
    Bar
}

public class TADA_NON_ENUM
{
}

public struct TADA_STRUCT
{
}

public class MyClass
{
    public void Test()
    {
        TADA[] t = new TADA[1];
        t.WriteCompressed(new MemoryStream()); //just fine
        TADA_NON_ENUM[] tne = new TADA_NON_ENUM[1];
        tne.WriteCompressed(new MemoryStream()); //compile time error
        TADA_STRUCT[] ts = new TADA_STRUCT[1];
        ts.WriteCompressed(new MemoryStream()); //compile time error
    }
}

public static class ExtensionClass
{
    public static void WriteCompressed<T>(this T[] towrite, Stream output) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");
        }
        //.... Function Code ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If possible I want to make it an extension, last resort if it's not possible. It shows up on intellisense if I call the class the extension is in but still won't let me call it.

Comment: Did you try the usage specified above? TADA[] t = new TADA[1];
t.WriteCompressed(new MemoryStream());

Comment: No but I know it will work. I'm just picky about wanting this as an extension. Worse comes to worse Ill settle for this. I know it's all pretty much the same, I'm just really picky.

Comment: Why would you say this is not an extension method? You can declare it as in the EDIT above.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't notice that, I just don't want it coming up on every array of any type that I create. I guess I could just name the function WriteCompressedEnums though. This will have to do for now, it seems the problem is that the language cannot cast an already defined enum array to an Enum[]. Thank you